# How do I get background color information for an element using Poltergeist and Capybara

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I am trying to migrate from testing using Firefox and Chrome to Poltergeist for integration tests.  One thing I am struggling with is getting the background color of an element.

Using Capybara/Selenium, this works:
find(:css, "locator").native.css_value('background-color')

Using Capybara/Poltergeist, I get an error that css_value is an undefined method.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having this problem at the moment